# How to exclude file patterns in vimgrep?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

In vim, I do search with vimgrep frequently. I have mapping like below:

```
map <leader>s :execute "noautocmd vimgrep /\\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\\>/gj **/*.*" <Bar> 
cw<CR> 5
```

The problem is that there are some temporary subfolders (like obj, objd) that I don't want to search for. How can I exclude subfolders matching given patterns. For example, subfolders with prefix "objd" should not be included in searching.

Comment: I didn't find any related options for vimgrep. Now I use grep instead.

Comment: You could use grep instead vimgrep. [Here](http://amix.dk/blog/post/175) explain how to use with script called MyGrep

Answer (score 40):

As of Vim 7.3.570, you can use wildignore to exclude patterns with vimgrep.

For example, to ignore the objd subfolder:

```
:set wildignore+=objd/**
```

Additional exclusions can be added by separating patterns with a comma:

```
:set wildignore+=objd/**,obj/**,*.tmp,test.c
```

See Vim's help documentation for a few more details.

```
:help wildignore
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect.  I've done `:set wildignore+=node_modules/**,.git/**` and yet my searches are still looking through node_modules and .git for results.  `vim --version | grep wildignore` showed me that my vim was compiled with wig support, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. My macbook's shell apparently doesn't support the `**` expansion.  In other shells you may have to do `shopt -s globstar` before you can use double-star expansions like this.

Comment: I wish this worked, but alas it doesn't for me. Running Vim version 8 on Ubuntu. Added `set wildignore+=node_modules/**,.git/**` to vimrc and still `e **/foo <tab>` still searches through the current directory's `node_modules`.

Comment: wildignore+=*/node_modules/** seems to work on my machine (windows)

Comment: works on archlinux :+1

Answer (score 21):

As showed in http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/03/combining-vimgrep-with-git-ls-files/ you could instead of exclude files, include the files you want to search. So you can search in the files tracked by Git with

```
:noautocmd vimgrep /{pattern}/gj `git ls-files`
```

In this way you are not searching the files stated in the `.gitignore`.

---

I use it so much I created a command for that, so I just need to

```
:Sch {pattern}
```

and I did it by adding the following line to my .vimrc

```
command -nargs=1 Sch noautocmd vimgrep /<args>/gj `git ls-files` | cw
```

Answer (score 12):

You could try [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) instead.  It integrates nicely with vim and has lots of options for doing the sort of thing you want to do.

There are several ack-vim integrations on GitHub.  For example: [here](http://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim).

Comment: Second github repository is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For example in Ubuntu just

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/bin/ack
```

then install http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572

and now add next line to your .vimrc

```
noremap <C-f> :copen<CR>:Ack --ignore-dir #first_ignore_dir# --ignore-dir #second_ignore_dir# -ai
```

- its open search frame by Ctr+F, have fun

Answer (score 0):

Seem to also ignore `node_modules` folder on root and if `node_modules` is in sub directories.

```
set wildignore+=*/node_modules/**
```