# vimgrep and filtering files searched

Tags: vim

How can I search for text in a files in a directory structure but ignore certain files.

For example, I want to be able to find the text `sometext` but not search files that match `*.gz`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude file patterns in vimgrep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898987/how-to-exclude-file-patterns-in-vimgrep)

Comment: Maybe you would be more interested in doing a `noautocmd vimgrep` which won't load plugins for those files. This will speed up searches considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can specify exclusions using the internal `vimgrep`.  You can, however, include multiple file wildcards so if you can specify all the files you're interested in that way there's no need for exclusion.  For example:

```
vimgrep /sometext/ *.c *.h *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
vimgrep /sometext/g `find ~ \( -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*py' \) -not path ~/tmp`
```

There is something called backtick expression, which provides the arguments to vimgrep: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/

Here the `find` command is being passed as a backtick expression, and find can exclude paths from vigrep.

The actual search term is long, but you dont have to type it all out. I usually just use `q:` to bring up the previous `ex` commands, search for the previous find command and modify it for the next search.